# Search a string for millions of terms with php

Tags: php, string, search

I have a string that I need to search using php to see if any of 2-3million terms are present.  The strings could be 1000 words long and the search terms may be up to 5 words long.

I have tried strpos and strstr but execution time is more than 60 seconds.

Can anyone suggest an alternative?

So far I have the following:

```
    $query = "SELECT City FROM cities";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        do {

            $city = " " . $row['City'] . " ";

            if(strpos($string, $city)!== False) {
                echo $city . "<br />\n";
                }

        } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    }
```

Comment: Where are the terms being stored? Are they in a database and you are querying them?

Comment: Perhaps add some more information about what you are trying to do and not how you are doing it.

Comment: I've added a little more detail.

Comment: You added FullText Search as a tag. But, why you are not doing it???

Comment: I didn't add it.. now removed

Comment: What is $string? Can you do a simple sql with where clause?

Comment: Have you considered a state machine like Aho-Corasick?

Comment: Why would you load the data from a database and perform search in PHP? A million entries at that size would most likely occupy 200+ megs of memory to store such an array in PHP. Then, you sequentially iterate trough every record and perform "searches". Of course it's slow! Use your database to filter out the results, that's what's it used for.

Comment: To identify a suitable solution for your problem there are so many other factors that require consideration here: how often does the data in your cities table change, can you use cache (what options are available to you here), what database engine are you using (MyIsam, InnoDB), could you use other languages to acheive this?, how often is the process run, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks all so far. The cities data does not change, not sure what cache options are available as I'm not sure of hosting arrangements yet, using mysql and the process would run approx 5k times a day. I'm mainly happy with php so would like to stick to it. The idea is that someone submits the text and I figure out which city they are writing about.

Comment: Thanks. N.B.'s comment guided me in the right direction. I created an array of many combinations of the words I needed and searched the database for those rather than the other way round. Sorted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Take the load from PHP and give to Mysql.

Here instead of doing the search with PHP inside a loop, you can use mysql LIKE function to search for a string.

eg: **SELECT** City **FROM** cities **LIKE** %search text%

if you have more search text, either you can use OR switch or **JOIN** sql queries to find those.

This will be quicker and you don't take 60 seconds for execution.

Good luck

-- Sajith

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following:

1. Using associative arrays create two lookup tables: words and terms, so each entry should represent single word/term
2. Now you can search through lookup tables with built in complexity `O(1)`

Comment: Unfortunately, whilst I have the cities in a table, I can't make the string into an array as some of the cities are more than 1 word.

Comment: @TomH but are they separated by something other than space?

Comment: no. 'Las Vegas' for example won't be matched if I explode all the string into words as 'las' and 'vegas' will be in separate records.